# pytest fail on github action. TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: django, pytest, github-actions, dotenv

When I run `pytest` locally, it works well. But it fails on GitHub Actions.

I set a secret key on GitHub secrets and uploaded `.env.test` to the GitHub repository both.

Is it a `dotenv` package problem or something else?

`workflow.yml`

```yaml
name: Django CI

on: [pull_request, push] # activates the workflow when there is a push or pull request in the repo

env:
  SERVER_ENV: "test"
  DEBUG: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
  SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
  DB_ENGINE: ${{secrets.DB_ENGINE}}
  DB_NAME: ${{secrets.DB_NAME}}
  USER: ${{secrets.USER}}
  PASSWORD: ${{secrets.PASSWORD}}
  POSTGRES_USER: ${{secrets.POSTGRES_USER}}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}}
  POSTGRES_DB: ${{secrets.POSTGRES_DB}}
  HOST: ${{secrets.HOST}}
  PORT: ${{secrets.PORT}}
  CELERY_BROKER_URL: ${{secrets.CELERY_BROKER_URL}}
  LOG_LEVEL: ${{secrets.LOG_LEVEL}}
  NAVER_NEWS_API_CLIENT_ID: ${{secrets.NAVER_NEWS_API_CLIENT_ID}}
  NAVER_NEWS_API_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{secrets.NAVER_NEWS_API_CLIENT_SECRET}}
  DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${{secrets.DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS}}

jobs:
  test_project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # operating system your code will run on
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          python3.8 -m venv env
          source env/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt # install all our dependencies for the project
      - name: Run Pytest
        run: pytest . # run pytest test
```

I tried like this
`workflow.yml`

```yaml
jobs:
  test_project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # operating system your code will run on
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Create venv
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          python3.8 -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: check python version
        run: python -V
      - name: check python version
        run: venv/bin/python -V
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt # install all our dependencies for the project
      - name: Run Pytest
        run: venv/bin/python -m pytest
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/bin/pytest", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 190, in console_main
    code = main()
           ^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 329, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 103, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config: Config = outcome.get_result()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1058, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1346, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1248, in _preparse
    self.hook.pytest_load_initial_conftests(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_django_dotenv/plugin.py", line 17, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(virtual_env_path, f'../{early_config.getini("env_path")[0]}'))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen posixpath>", line 76, in join
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

`requirements.txt`

```py
amqp==5.1.1
asgiref==3.6.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==22.2.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1;python_version<"3.9"
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
black==22.12.0
celery==5.2.7
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
Django==4.0.8
django-celery-beat==2.4.0
django-dotenv==1.4.2
django-environ==0.9.0
django-timezone-field==5.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
exceptiongroup==1.1.0
execnet==1.9.0
flower==1.2.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
humanize==4.4.0
idna==3.4
iniconfig==1.1.1
kombu==5.2.4
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
packaging==22.0
pathspec==0.10.3
platformdirs==2.6.0
pluggy==1.0.0
prometheus-client==0.15.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
PyJWT==2.6.0
pytest==7.2.0
pytest-django==4.5.2
pytest-django-dotenv==0.1.2
pytest-xdist==3.1.0
python-crontab==2.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.7
redis==4.4.0
requests==2.28.1
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.3
tomli==2.0.1
tornado==6.2
typing_extensions==4.4.0
tzdata==2022.7
urllib3==1.26.13
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
```

`pytest.ini`

```ini
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = modu_property.settings
python_files = test*.py
django_find_project = true
env_path = ./.env.test
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = DEBUG
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_cli_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

`settings.py`

```py
import datetime
import json
from pathlib import Path

import environ
import os

from celery.schedules import crontab

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    # DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

# Set the project base directory
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


def set_logging():
    return {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "filters": {
            "require_debug_false": {
                "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse",
            },
            "require_debug_true": {
                "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue",
            },
        },
        "formatters": {
            "django.server": {
                "()": "django.utils.log.ServerFormatter",
                "format": "{asctime} {filename}:{funcName}:{lineno} [{levelname}] {message}",
                "style": "{",
            },
        },
        "handlers": {
            "django.server": {
                "level": env("LOG_LEVEL"),
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "formatter": "django.server",
            },
            "file": {
                "level": env("LOG_LEVEL"),
                "filters": ["require_debug_true"],
                "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/modu_property.log",
                "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
                "backupCount": 5,
                "formatter": "django.server",
            },
        },
        "loggers": {
            "django.server": {
                "handlers": ["django.server"],
                "level": env("LOG_LEVEL"),
                "propagete": True,
            },
            "file": {
                "handlers": ["file"],
                "level": env("LOG_LEVEL"),
                "propagete": True,
            },
        },
    }


# FROM .env.* file
SERVER_ENV = os.environ.get("SERVER_ENV")
if SERVER_ENV == "dev":
    environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env.dev"))
elif SERVER_ENV == "stage":
    environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env.stage"))
# elif SERVER_ENV == "prod":
#     environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env.prod"))
elif SERVER_ENV == "test":
    environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env.test"))
else:
    environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env.local"))
LOGGING = set_logging()


# False if not in os.environ because of casting above
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")

# Raises Django's ImproperlyConfigured
# exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

CELERY_BROKER_URL = env("CELERY_BROKER_URL")


ENGINE = env("DB_ENGINE")
NAME = env("DB_NAME")
USER = env("USER")
PASSWORD = env("PASSWORD")
HOST = env("HOST")
PORT = env("PORT")
NAVER_NEW_API_CLIENT_ID = env("NAVER_NEW_API_CLIENT_ID")
NAVER_NEW_API_CLIENT_SECRET = env("NAVER_NEW_API_CLIENT_SECRET")
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS = env("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS", default="").split(" ")
ALLOWED_HOSTS = DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS
POSTGRES_USER = env("POSTGRES_USER", default="")
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", default="")
POSTGRES_DB = env("POSTGRES_DB", default="")

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "app",
    "accounts",
    "modu_property",
    "django_celery_beat",
    # "rest_framework_simplejwt",
]

# TODO : rest_framework_simplejwt 설정 필요 없으면 제거
# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
#         "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
#     )
# }

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    # "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "modu_property.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "modu_property.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": ENGINE,
        "NAME": NAME,
        "USER": USER,
        "PASSWORD": PASSWORD,
        "HOST": HOST,
        "PORT": PORT,
    },
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": datetime.timedelta(hours=6),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": datetime.timedelta(days=14),
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("JWT",),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"

# Celery Configuration Options
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "UTC"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
CELERY_BROKER_URL = CELERY_BROKER_URL
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json"]
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "collect_property_news_every_5_minutes": {
        "task": "modu_property.tasks.collect_property_news_task",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/5"),
        "args": json.dumps(
            {
                "days": 100,
            }
        ),
    },
}
```

[image]

venv local interpreter
[image]

Comment: Have you verified, for example with `ls` command, that the `.env.test` file exists and is accessible by Python scripts?

Comment: Also, the `env` key where you've listed all the env vars is placed under the checkout step so their visibility is under that step only. From the configuration, it sure looks like you wanted these to be visible for the rest of the steps as well so you need to place those globally (i.e. per job or maybe for all the jobs but for now there's only one job). Please see docs (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow) for more details.

Comment: Apart from that, you might want to contain all your dependencies contained in a [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for replying. I changed env setting. but still got error..

Comment: @Azeem and I checked .env.test is existed

Comment: Same error "**TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType**"?

Comment: @Azeem Yes, same ..

  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_django_dotenv/plugin.py", line 17, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(virtual_env_path, f'../{early_config.getini("env_path")[0]}'))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen posixpath>", line 76, in join
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: Right. I think it's mostly on your side to debug this by printing `env_path`, adding logs for `pytest.ini`, and tracking down why it's not present there and results into a `NoneType`. Also, could you please confirm and add it to your question as well whether you're using `venv` locally or not?

Comment: @Azeem I use venv locally. And I did pip freeze to requirements.txt. By the way do you mean log.info(env_path) to pytest.ini file?? I did not understand well.

Comment: Right. You should try and use `venv` on GitHub Actions as well. I was referring to tracking down that exception to its root cause by using logs. Apparently, `os.path.join()` doesn't return a valid string and that's what is causing that exception.

Comment: @Azeem I changed workflow file to use venv but still same error. I wrote changed codes on question. 

    dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(virtual_env_path, f'../{early_config.getini("env_path")[0]}'))
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: @Azeem oh I changed install order.       - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          python3.8 -m venv env
          source env/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt # install all our dependencies for the project then Run pytest .
/home/runner/work/_temp/ff65180f-0bbf-4361-941f-3588951eabbd.sh: line 1: pytest: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

Comment: Run python3 -m pytest
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/bin/python3: No module named pytest
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: I tried python3 -m pytest, python -m pytest, pytest, pytest3.8 -m pytest... not works

Comment: hmmm... I used python from venv but error raised....

Comment: @Azeem I solved problem. Thank you a lot! You really helped me. But I still confuse why I have to use venv on github action...

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome! :) GitHub runners already have preinstalled software on them (including Python). So, it's always a good practice to contain our deps using a virtual environment. I would use `venv` for any non-trivial Python work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `pytest` after activating `venv` and the build was successful:

```yaml
jobs:
  test_project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          python3.8 -m venv env
          source env/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pytest .
```